# Fullwidth responsive two column layout image and text

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to look for clues to design a banner like the one on the top of this page: https://www.gazteaukera.euskadi.eus/inicio/

I am trying myself but don't get what I want (see below). I want to have an image column on the left and a text column on the right perfectly aligned. I want it to be responsive, so that in smaller screens the left column will be placed on top of the right column (with no space between top and bottom divs).

I am having some issues getting what I want. I hope someone can help me :)

**code:**

```css
    .row {
      background-color: blue;
      padding: 0px;
    /*I have added a background-color to help me solve the design issues, but this is sthg to be removed*/}
    
    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 0px;
     }
     
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .title {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #0FD955;
    padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;}
    
    .text {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #0FD955;
    padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
    }
    
    .imgw100 {
    width: 100%;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {  
      .column {    width: 100%;  }
        .right {    width: 100%;  }
      .left {    width: 100%;  }
    
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column right">
      <img class="imgw100" src="https://butterfly-conservation.org/sites/default/files/styles/masthead/public/2019-03/16548509661_3bdddd5179_o.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="column left" style="background-color: #022C11;">
        <p class="title">Breaking news</p>
        <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add display css to row as flex for larger devices
add for small screen add display css as block for row

```css
.row {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

.title {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #0fd955;
    padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.text {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #0fd955;
    padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.imgw100 {
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .row {
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 0px;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not familair with bootstrap. I'll check it out, but I hope there is some way of doing it with pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: i will edit the answer please check through this

Comment: Hi Dinesh, thank you very much for you help but It doesn't seem to work. I will try with bootstrap instead.